# GKE/Istio: outside world cannot connect to service in private cluster

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, istio

I've created a private GKE cluster with Istio through the Cloud Console UI. The cluster is set up with VPC Peering to be able to reach another private GKE cluster in another Google Cloud Project.

I've created a Deployment (called `website`) with a Service in Kubernetes in the `staging` namespace. My goal is to expose this service to the outside world with Istio, using the Envoy proxy. I've created the necessary `VirtualService` and `Gateway` to do so, following [this guide](https://istio.io/docs/tasks/traffic-management/ingress/).

When running "kubectl exec ..." to access a pod in the private cluster, I can successfully connect to the internal IP address of the `website` service, and see the output of that service with "curl".

I have set up a NAT Gateway so pods in the private cluster can connect to the Internet. I confirmed this by `curl`-ing various non-Google web pages from within the `website` pod.

However, I can't connect to the `website` service from the outside, using the `External IP` of the `istio-ingressgateway` service, as the guide above mentions. Instead, `curl`-ing that `External IP` leads to a timeout.

I've put the full YAML config for all related resources in a private Gist, here: https://gist.github.com/marceldegraaf/0f36ca817a8dba45ac97bf6b310ca282

I'm wondering if I'm missing something in my config here, or if my use case is actually impossible?

Comment: If you're just using external IP of a node, rather than a LoadBalancer or Ingress, you'll need to make sure your GCE firewall rules allow the traffic.

Comment: @PaulAnnetts thanks for your reply. The `External IP` of the `istio-ingressgateway` is bound to a forwarding rule in Cloud Load Balancer, with the GKE nodes as the Target Pool. I've added a Firewall Rule to explicitly allow all incoming traffic on TCP:80 for the entire network, but even then my `curl` to the `External IP` results in a timeout. Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: Did you check the logs for istio-ingressgateway? If your service is getting hit and if the service has some error, it would show in that log.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @mjkool. When checking the logs for `istio-ingressgateway` I see no requests coming in when trying to access the `External IP` from outside. I do see requests in the logs of `istio-ingressgateway` when I try to `curl` it from inside the cluster.

Comment: @MarceldeGraaf, any solution to the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your Gist I suspect the problem lies in the joining up of the `Gateway` to the `istio-ingressgateway`.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: website-gateway
  namespace: staging
  labels:
    version: v1
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway
  servers:
    - port:
        number: 80
        name: http
        protocol: HTTP
      hosts:
        - "*"
```

In particular I'm not convinced the `selector` part is correct.

You should be able to do something like
`kubectl describe po -n istio-system istio-ingressgateway-rrrrrr-pppp`
to find out what the selector is trying to match in the Istio Ingress Gateway pod.

Comment: Thanks! It does seem the `istio-ingressgateway` has this label, see the output of `kubectl describe pod` here: https://gist.github.com/marceldegraaf/0f36ca817a8dba45ac97bf6b310ca282#file-istio-ingressgateway-describe-pod-L8. That should correctly join the `Gateway` to the `istio-ingressgateway` pod, right?

Comment: Have you checked the logs of the GCP load balancer, and also that the LB’s health check is in a healthy state?

Comment: The LB health check is green and there are no errors in the load balancer logs.

Comment: Ok so the LB is talking to *something* - you should be able to find log entries from the LB pings in `istio-ingressgateway` pod if it's wired up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. On my case, the istio virtual service dont find my service.

Try this on your VirtualService:

```
   route:
   - destination:
       host: website
       port: 
         number: 80
```

Answer (score -1):

From verifying all options, the only way to have the private GKE cluster with Istio to be exposed to externally is to use [Cloud NAT](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/overview).

Since the Master node within GKE is a managed service, there are current limits when using Istio with a private cluster. The only workaround that would accomplish your use case is to use Cloud NAT. I have also attached an article on how to get started using Cloud NAT [here](https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/using-nat).

Comment: Thanks! I did set up Cloud NAT but as mentioned in my original question that doesn't solve the issue for me.

Comment: As I have tested the past, using Cloud NAT specifically, it works; however, using a seperate NAT gateway, it will not work. As you mentioned in your original post, you only mentioned using a NAT gateway. Make sure that you are specifically using Google Cloud NAT for allowing the cluster to communicate externally.